# How to auto switch between HAProxy Peers

Tags: docker, load-balancing, haproxy

I have two HAProxy instances/peers. I would like it so that if one goes down, application starts using other.

This is relevant part from `haproxy.cfg`

```
backend haproxy_http
    stick-table type ip size 20k peers hapeers
    stick on src
    balance roundrobin
    option tcp-check
    server n1 someIP check port 80
    server n2 someIP2 check port 80

peers hapeers
   peer ha1 haproxyIP1:1024
   peer ha2 haproxyIP2:1024
```

There are two HAProxy instances running as two difference containers/**docker-services**.

On a single instance, my application just connected to port revealed by the only HAProxy server. On two instances, I am not sure how to make the switch to other instance automatically since I have two ports (one revealed by HAProxy1 and other by HAProxy2) now.

Something like:

- Tries connecting to HAProxy1.
- HAProxy1 is down; connects to HAProxy 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a service like keepalived to implement the failover. In regards to the use of "peers", according to the haproxy manual:

"
During a soft restart, local peer : is used by the old instance to connect the new one and initiate a complete replication (teaching process).
"

This is not talking about failover, but a soft restart.

Source: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#3.5

Comment: if you use peers you dont need keepalived